# Change entry in a JSON list that matches a condition without discarding rest of document

Tags: json, bash, edit, jq

I am trying to open a file, look through the file and change a value based on the value and pass this either to a file or var.
Below is an example of the JSON

```
{
     "Par": [
         {
             "Key": "12345L",
             "Value": "https://100.100.100.100:100",
             "UseLastValue": true
         },
         {
             "Key": "12345S",
             "Value": "VAL2CHANGE",
             "UseLastValue": true
         },
         {
             "Key": "12345T",
             "Value": "HAPPY-HELLO",
             "UseLastValue": true
         }
     ],
      "CANCOPY": false,
      "LOGFILE": ["HELPLOG"]
 }
```

i have been using jq and i have been successful in isolating the object group and change the value.

```
 cat jsonfile,json | jq '.Par | map(select(.Value=="VAL2CHANGE")) | .[] | .Value="VALHASBEENCHANGED"'
```

This gives

```
         {
             "Key": "12345S",
             "Value": "VALHASBEENCHANGED",
             "UseLastValue": true
         }
```

What id like to achieve is to retain the full JSON output with the changed value

```
{
     "Par": [
         {
             "Key": "12345L",
             "Value": "https://100.100.100.100:100",
             "UseLastValue": true
         },
         {
             "Key": "12345S",
             "Value": "VALHASBEENCHANGED",
             "UseLastValue": true
         },
         {
             "Key": "12345T",
             "Value": "HAPPY-HELLO",
             "UseLastValue": true
         }
     ],
      "CANCOPY": false,
      "LOGFILE": ["HELPLOG"]
 }
```

I.E.

```
jq '.Par | map(select(.Value=="VAL2CHANGE")) | .[] | .Value="VALHASBEENCHANGED"' (NOW PUT IT BACK IN FILE)
```

OR

open file, look in file, file value to be changed and change this and output this to a file or to screen

To add, the json file will only contain the value im looking for once as im creating this. If any other values need changing i will name differently.

Comment: BTW, using `cat` here is bad practice -- better to run `jq '...' foo.json` or `jq '...' <foo.json`, either of which will give `jq` a seekable handle on the real input file, rather than starting two separate programs (`cat` and `jq`) and giving `jq` a non-seekable FIFO that reads from `cat`. That's an extra big deal for programs like `sort` that can parallelize (forking into subprocesses that handle a subset of the input file) or seek (f/e, asking for metadata like file size in constant time, like `wc -c`, or skipping to the end like `tail`) to improve performance when given a real FD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jq --arg match "VAL2CHANGE" \
   --arg replace "VALHASBEENCHANGED" \
  '.Par |= map(if .Value == $match then (.Value=$replace) else . end)' \
  <in.json
```

To more comprehensively replace a string anywhere it may be in a nested data structure, you can use the `walk` function -- which will be in the standard library in jq 1.6, but can be manually pulled in in 1.5:

```
jq --arg match "VAL2CHANGE" \
   --arg replace "VALHASBEENCHANGED" '

# taken from jq 1.6; will not be needed here after that version is released.
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

walk(if . == $match then $replace else . end)' <in.json
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just replacing based on the values, you could stream the file and replace the values as you rebuild the result.

```
$ jq --arg change 'VAL2CHANGE' --arg value 'VALHASBEENCHANGED' -n --stream '
fromstream(inputs | if length == 2 and .[1] == $change then .[1] = $value else . end)
' input.json
```

Comment: This is a great general point, though -- no reason to load the whole document into memory when the change can be streamed.